# How I should use await in .push?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have some database (its hosting database, on Repl.it):

```
568481051895136279: 'Lizia-test'
789481847895132112: 'Master-test'
854469844372160512: 'Aomira'
333652270895857674: 'ewt '
```

(user.id as 'key' and some string as 'value')

I using next command to insert data:
`db.set("key", "value");`

and this command to get data:
`temp = db.get("key");`

I'm creating array with user.id's who reacted on message:

```js
  fetchMsg.reactions.cache.map(async (reaction) => {
  let usersThatReacted = []; //Initiates usersThatReacted as an array
  if (reaction.emoji.name !== ":thumbsup:") return; //If the reaction checked isn't equal to :thumbsup:, return
  let reactedUsers = await reaction.users.fetch(); //Fetches the users that reacted with the :thumbsup: on the collected message
    reactedUsers.map((user) => { //Maps out every user that reacted with :thumbsup:
      usersThatReacted.push(user.id); //Pushes each user id's into the array
    });
  message.channel.send(usersThatReacted);
```

And after that I have a message from bot with:

> 568481051895136279
> 789481847895132112
> 854469844372160512
> 333652270895857674

But I wanna get values from db by these user IDs instead of users id, and I tried change this:
usersThatReacted.push(user.id); I've changed to usersThatReacted.push(db.get(user.id));
But :( I have next in message from bot:

> [object Promise]
> [object Promise]
> [object Promise]
> [object Promise]

Yea, i understand, that i must use some await, but second day finding information and trying, but cant do anytning(
Help anyone, if u can( what i should do to get from bot:

> Lizia-test
> Master-test
> Aomira
> ewt

Comment: `.map` is designed to transform and you return the data you want from your passed in function, so using it to `.push` to another array does not make any sense. `const usersThatReacted = reactedUsers.map((user) => user.id);`

Comment: Also, if you have an array of promises, `await Promise.all(arr)` would get you the values.

Comment: `const usersThatReacted = await Promise.all(reactedUsers.map((user) => db.get(user.id)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69013148/how-i-should-use-await-in-push#comment121970812_69013148), you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). This will automatically await all of the promises in the array and return an array (it is a promise which will have to be awaited)

```js
message.channel.send(await (Promise.all(usersThatReacted))
```

<sub>Untested code. If you get any errors just comment and I will try my best to fix it</sub>